# Wireshark Lua Dissector - How to set source and destination

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm working on a Wireshark Dissector in Lua.

I try to provide wireshark as much information about my custom protocol as possible to make use of the available analysis tools. Therefore I'm trying to set the correct source and destination address for my protocol.

My protocol can be on top of different other protocols such as UDP or IEEE 802.15.4. So it might even be that the package source/destination is already set (UDP).

However I want wireshark to show my addresses, so I tried the following:

```
myproto = Proto("myproto"), "My Protocol")
myproto_source = ProtoField.uint16("myproto.src", "Source Address", base.HEX)
myproto.fields = { myproto_source }

function myproto.dissector(buffer, pinfo, tree)
    local subtree = tree:add(myproto, buffer(), "My Proto")

    subtree:add(myproto_source, buffer(0,2)

    -- does not work with error:
    -- bad argument #1 to '?' (Address expected, got userdata)
    pinfo.src = myproto_source

    -- does work, but only adds text, wireshark tools rely on pinfo.src
    pinfo.cols.src = tostring(buffer(0,2):uint())
end

udp_table = DissectorTable.get("udp.port")
udp_table:add( 12345, myproto )
wtap_encap_table = DissectorTable.get("wtap_encap")
wtap_encap_table:add(wtap["IEEE802_15_4"], myproto)
```

So is there maybe a datatype/class "address" that is necessary to set `pinfo.src`? Or is there a totally different way to set the packet information?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pinfo.src` takes an [`Address`](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/lua_module_Pinfo.html#lua_class_Address) object (which is an IP address; not a 16-bit integer). Example usage:

```
pinfo.src = Address.ip('1.2.3.4')
```

Note that this only sets the text of the "Source" column shown in Wireshark. The underlying packet info **cannot** be modified, and the IP packet details will continue to show the actual IP address.

Comment: not quite what I was hoping for, but very helpful explanation!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion - I'm not an LUA wiz:

```
pinfo:col.src = buffer(0,2):uint()
```

maybe??

Comment: It would have to be

    `pinfo.cols.src = buffer(0,2):uint()`

which actually sets the column information, even though it is still not recognized by the wireshark tools (i.e. flow graph)